# C# chart XValue is empty

Tags: c#, charts, xvalue

I have a problem with getting value of AxisX.

I add new points form `dataTable`:

```
chart1.Series.Add(dataTable.Columns[x].Caption);
chart1.Series[dataTable.Columns[x].Caption].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
chart1.Series[dataTable.Columns[x].Caption].BorderWidth = 1;

for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    chart1.Series[dataTable.Columns[x].Caption].Points
           .AddXY(dataTable.Rows[i][0], dataTable.Rows[i][x]);
```

and I use mouse_move event to get the values and show them in the labels.

```
private void chart1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
        Point mousePoint = new Point(e.X, e.Y);

        var pos = e.Location;
        if (prevPosition.HasValue && pos == prevPosition.Value)
            return;
        tooltip.RemoveAll();
        prevPosition = pos;
        var results = chart1.HitTest(pos.X, pos.Y, false,
                                        ChartElementType.DataPoint);
        foreach (var result in results)
        {
            if (result.ChartElementType == ChartElementType.DataPoint)
            {
                var prop = result.Object as DataPoint;
                if (prop != null)
                {
                        tooltip.Show("X=" + DateTime.FromOADate(prop.XValue) + "\n Y=" + prop.YValues[0], this.chart1,
                                        pos.X, pos.Y - 15);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

It's strange that `prop.XValue` is empty. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is it empty or null or is the conversion `DateTime.FromOADate(prop.XValue)` failing? Can you  show `prop.XValue.ToString()` instead?

Comment: [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25937396/fgh3.jpg) Here is breakpoints of two ways of taking value and showed as it looks.

Comment: Hm. Strange. Can you show me how the X-axis label is set? Is there more than one series? What is the original datatype for X?

Comment: ok, I take data from database. `tooltip.Show("X=" + dataTable.Rows[result.PointIndex][0].ToString() + "\n Y=" + prop.YValues[0], this.chart1,
                                            pos.X, pos.Y - 15);`

Comment: I have another question. Do you know function `var results = chart1.HitTest(pos.X, pos.Y, false, ChartElementType.DataPoint);` 
I want to take consider only `pos.X`.    `Pos.Y` can be whatever.

Comment: What is the question? It seems to work for me. Copying your code shows my XValues fine. Could it be that the values are very small?

Comment: I handle with it. Now it's working. Thanks :)

Comment: You can use the built-in label and tooltip keywords, to show x and y values automatically on each `DataPoint`. When adding the points to the series, do `point.Label = "#VALX";`, or `point.Tooltip = "#VALX;"`, for instance.